# using focus on my css but some tag is not showing on chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It is supposed to show the dotted box when you hit tag key
for my other contents like bar and links work perfectly fine
but it is not showing on my footer nor my image(But the tag is on it, just not showing the
dotted box) 
It also works when I use firefox!!

my html:

```
<footer>

    <div class = "line">
    <p>CALL US!</p>
    <p>206-555-1212</p>
    <a class"email"  href="mailto:dawgpizzaseattle@gmail.com"><p>Email</p></a>
    <a class="twitter" href="http://twitter.com/dawgpizzasea"><p>Twitter</p></a>
    </div>

</footer>
```

css:

```
:focus {

    outline: #FFF dotted 2px;
    background-color: #000;

}

.content-box :focus img {

    outline: #FFF dotted 2px;

}
```

image:

```
<a href="index.html"><img class = "logo" src="img/logo.png" alt = "logo"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
footer:focus {

outline: #FFF dotted 2px; background-color: #000;

}
```

Comment: It is not working, the problem is that when you hit tag. the tag is on it, just the box is not showing, which is really confusing

Comment: Its better u create a js fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Put the links into paragraphs, not the other way around. 
Links are inline and paragraphs are block level content, and you shouldn't put blocks into inline elements - this will fix the footer problem.

The logo link will have to be styled to display the dotted border around the image, and there are many different ways to do this - here's one:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/7Csj4/1/

Be sure to click somewhere in the result box before hitting tab to see the focus move.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! footer is fixed now. but my image is still not working? I set the a.logo to inline block.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Can you put your code in a fiddle so i can see what's wrong? The image in the one I've posted works (you might have to hit shift+tab to move the focus backwards).